# Rails - query for where has parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have this simple association

```
class User
    has_many :items

class Item
    belongs_to :item
```

I'm not sure how to write a query to find all Items that has/hasnt a user.

I tried this but user isn't a column I can query on the Item

```
Item.where(:user => nil)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean

```
class Item
  belongs_to :user
```

Then do this:

```
Item.where(:user_id => nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean query all the items which reference a user that doesn't exists.

```
Item.includes(:user).where('users.id is null')
```